# blank page pops when i try to connect to database to create a simple login page using php and mysql using xampp

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, xampp

I have used the following code but when I click on the login button I'm redirected to a blank page.in this I have created a login pAGE that checks if the user is present in database.I have not given a sign up page instead manually added values to the database.In sign-in.html I have given the form and in connectivity.php file I have given the code to check if user and password are present in database.
as per code the output should have been "successfully logged in" or "error could not login" but instead I get a blank page.how do I resolve this.please help!!
the php file that connects to db:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please put your code here, not in images.

Comment: Please, post your code as plain text rather than a picture of it.

Comment: `$row = mysql_fetch_array($query); or die(mysql_error());` What's the purpose of the semicolon after mysql_fetch_array()?

Comment: first of all please put code here? second switch to `mysqli_*` or `PDO`. `mysql_*` is deprecated.

Comment: In the last screenshot you invoke the php file directly, through the file system, not through a webserver. This way the php file is not run.

Comment: clahari pleas put your code here. remove the images.